# simplebar-angular is not working, Error: Cannot find module 'simplebar-angular' or its corresponding type declarations | Anguler

Tags: angular, simplebar

```
simplebar-angular is not working, Error: Cannot find module 'simplebar-angular' or its corresponding type declarations | Angular
```

**install command I've tried as below**

```
npm i simplebar-angular
yarn add simplebar-angular
```

it's added after installation in the **package.json** as below,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",   
    "simplebar-angular": "^3.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

after adding the package I'm importing it to **app.module.ts** as below,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SimplebarAngularModule } from 'simplebar-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SimplebarAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**please check the below error images**,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've also tried all the steps after the clean catch as below,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but still facing the same error,
please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should also install the dependencies for simplebar-angular. In your case you need to install simplebar-core [Link is here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplebar-core) . You can check this stackblitz [Link is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplebar-angular-demo). You can compare your dependencies with this live example. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've tried to install both packages and tray again but facing the same issue.
please check the below links for error info.

https://prnt.sc/DQmkcpcvbdy0
https://prnt.sc/8O8xUDMCEFAq